# Как отследить события в Owl Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

Я хочу повесить событие следующего типа, когда меняется активный Item то из Активного брать текст и помещать в блок
Вот мой код

```
$('#section_home_carousel').on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {
    $('.report_content p').text(
        $(this).find('.owl-item.active').find('.item_hidden_content p').text()
    );
});
```

Но он берет текст из пред идущего блока или из следующего, такое впечатление будто он не успевает переклюсить клас актив

Comment: сделай пример воспроизводящий ошибку, и добавь ссылку на документацию библиотеки

Comment: Ошибки нет, дело в том что когда происходит событие класс Active переходит на следующий Item, но текст берется не из активного как написано у меня а из пред идущего. Все бы ничего если бы слайдер работал в одну сторону можно написать типо .prev() но он работает в две стороны и по этому нужно выдергивать текст именно из Активного

Comment: Поэтому и я говорю, про пример, который можно запустить и увидеть описанное поведение.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yt5Lk0pq/
Но тут както странно выводит прямо все заголовки, но можешь смотреть что происходит с первой цифрой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в event.item.index хранится индекс нового активного блока,
пример (на базе твоего): https://jsfiddle.net/4b8a2s3d/

```
$('.owl-carousel').on('changed.owl.carousel', function(event) {    
    console.log(event.item.index);
}
```